# Trying to count total number of rows in a table using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to count the total number of rows present in a table using PHP & Mysql.I need to send all of these data to another page for view purpose.

ex:

```
  id | fname | lname |
  1  |ak     | pk    |
  2  |aks    | pks   |
  3  |akss   | pkss  |
```

for example,above one should return 3.I don't exactly know how to send all of the data and use it on another page and print it.
Below is the code which I am trying to run but its not working.

```
$sql= $db->query("SELECT * from student");
        $row= $sql->fetch_array();
        $totalrow= mysqli_num_row($sql);

        for($i=0;$i<**??**;$i++)  // I don't know how to get the total rows 
        {
           $data[$i][0]= $row['id'];
           $data[$i][1]= $row['fname'];
           $data[$i][2]= $row['lname'];

          $row=$sql->fetch_array();
        }
        return ($data);
```

Comment: A look in the manual usually solves the problem.

Comment: `$totalrow= mysqli_num_row($sql);` this returns what you want. What more you want ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @krishna yeah but its not working also I want to return the whole data to another page where I can print them,how shall I do it?

Comment: use while loop and store data in session array....

Comment: try using `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysqli_num_row`.

Comment: @krishna what about the second part , how shall i retrieve the data on other page and print it there?

Comment: you could use sessions . Store all the data in sessions and in the next page get value from sessions and display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql=$db->prepare('SELECT id FROM students');
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_results();
$total=$sql->num_rows();
$sql->close();
return$total;
```

Returning row data

```
function getStudents(){
    $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT id, fname, lname FROM students');
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($id,$fname,lname);
    while($sql->fetch()){
        $students[]=array('id'=>$id,'fname'=>$fname,'lname'=>$lname);
    }
    $sql->close();
    return$students;
}
$students=getStudents();
//if you print $students it should look: Array([0]=>Array('id'=>1,'fname'=>'ak','lname'=>'pk')[1]=>Array('id'=>2,'fname'=>'aks','lname'=>'pks')[2]=>Array('id'=>3,'fname'=>'akss','lname'=>'pkss'))
```

With this array you can use a foreach.

```
echo"<table><th>ID</th><th>fname</th><th>lname</th>";
foreach($students as$student){
    //now the array students is 'split' into student. student is now Array('id'=>1,'fname'=>'ak','lname'=>'pk'); and so on.
    echo"<tr><td>".$student['id']."</td><td>".$student['fname']."</td><td>".$student['lname']."</td></tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

Same page processing.

```
<?php 
    function getStudents(){
        $db=new mysqli('local','user','pass','database');//obviously put outside of function if used elsewhere
        $sql=$db->prepare('SELECT id, fname, lname FROM students');
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->bind_result($id,$fname,$lname);
        while($sql->fetch()){
            $students[]=Array('id'=>$id,'fname'=>$fname,'lname'=>$lname);
        }
        $sql->close();
        return$students;
    }
    $students=getStudents();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--other doc head stuff here-->
</head>
<body>
    <nav><ol><li><a href="">Home</a></li></ol></nav>
    <!-- more body stuff blahh blahh-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            foreach($students as $student){
                echo"<tr><td>".$student['id']."</td><td>".$student['fname']."</td><td>".$student['lname']."</td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it's all neatly within one page and you don't have to fuss about using `$_GET`. Hope this helps :)

Please also note that mysql is depreciated. [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) is now what is used.

Comment: can you tell me how shall I retrieve this data on some other page and print it there?

Comment: Explain why this is -1 for OP's sake! @YourCommonSense

Comment: This was a legitimate answer. I think @YourCommonSense -1'd. But it does exactly what was asked in the OP.

Comment: @Abhinay you want the data to return to another page? Could you use `require()`?

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @Beneto I placed it inside function and calling this function on other page string value like $data= list(); but Its not working. what about the print part do i need to use loops again?

Comment: @Abhinay did you want to get the data as well as the current row_count? My answer only gets the row count. Your Common Sense's answer only 'gets' the data from the table.

Comment: @Beneto OP's main idea is getting row count and to store the values into a array `data`. so there is no wrong in what `Your Common Sense` has written

Comment: @Beneto hey, I am sorry but I wanted to know the row count because I need to use it as a conditional statmnt in my for loop but my main issue is simply get the list of all data from table and get them on other page then print it there.so I decided to place code inside a function then call that function on the required page and print it there.So, how shall I do it.I think I don't necessarily require row count.

Comment: @krishna I never said it was wrong. Only that the OP has asked two questions within one and that people are getting confused. Getting the number of rows within a table and getting the data are two entirely different things :p

Comment: @Beneto what about printing the data on other page. do i need to run a loop there? can you please tell me how shall I print it if I am using a function to get these data.

Comment: @Abhinay no you don't require a row count to retrieve data from a table. I think I'm following you with the other page idea? How are you getting to this other page?

Comment: @Beneto sorry If I am confusing you but I really need to know how to get these data and print it on another page. :)

Comment: @Abhinay that's alright :) What's the other page's format? HTML,PHP? I'll give you an example. You don't require HTTPRequests do you?

Comment: @Beneto its a HTML page where I am calling this. Yes this is a GET request page.

Comment: @Abhinay Ahh ok. javascript or no javascript? Seems a bit too far fetched to use get. Could I suggest another method? Does it require user interaction? Pressing a button to require the students?

Comment: @Beneto Yeah if you can suggest another method which will work here. I would love to use it.

Comment: @Abhinay easiest option is to put the script at the top of you document. Preferably above `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Then use when needed. I'll put it in my answer.

Comment: @Beneto I am getting this error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in line 10

Comment: @Abhinay use mysqli rather than mysql. That error is more than likely to do with your Query. Look at the line `prepare('SELECT id, fname, lname FROM students')` make sure all is correct.

Comment: @Abhinay If you've copied what I've written, you'll notice I've used 'students' rather than 'student' as the table name. Change that

Comment: @Beneto getting this error now : Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_results(), 
Yeah I have corrected the table name.

Comment: @Beneto Hey I got it, thank you . I just have to change it to bind_result instead of bind_results.I really liked your determination towards resolving other's issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhinay That's alright :) I like to help. Sorry about my errors lol

Answer (score 0):

```
 $totalrow= $sql->rowCount();
```

Comment: This is a method of the [PDOStatement class](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Question is tagged [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).